# DisconnectedContext exception on closing a Window

Tags: wpf, exception, visual-studio-2015, window

I create a new WPF Windows using the following code:

```
var window = new Window();
window.Title = draggingTabItem.Header as string;
window.Content = stateViewer; // this is an UserControl, it works
window.LocationChanged += Window_OnLocationChanged;
window.Show();
```

No when lateron I call

```
SelectedWindow.Close()
```

I get DisconnectedContext exception. I cannot find any information about this exception. What is this exception about and how do I resolved it?

[image]

I found [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ac2e658-0ec9-4672-9881-51f4203d147e/how-to-resolve-disconnectedcontext-was-detected-exception?forum=csharplanguage#a9d554f2-099b-4638-afe0-5e7458e62737) on MSDN, but I would like to have something which doesn't throw the error in the first place.

Comment: The exception is harmless and it is not really related to your code but the debugging session in Visual Studio. It won't be raised when the application is run outside of Visual Studio so you could just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up disabling DisconnectedContext and ContextSwitchDeadlock, which I got after the first, in the Exception Settings.

[image]